# AWS SSO and CodeArtifact Login requires manual config file changes for Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-regions, aws-codeartifact, aws-sso

When I run

```
AWS SSO Login --Profile Default
```

on my machine if my .aws/config file is not set to a Default region of **us-east-1** I get "Invalid Grant" When the Browser opens to authenticate. When I set the config region to **us-west-2** I can authenticate.

Issue is I then need to login to CodeArtifact and if I do not change the config file to us-west-2 I get:

```
An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: Domain not found. Domain 'MY-domain' owned by account '1234567890' does not exist.
```

I need to be able to login to CodeArtifact inside of a docker container and manually changing the region is not an option there. Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS CLI has [global parameters](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/index.html) you can use to pass the region when calling `get-authorization-token`.

`aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain MY-domain --region us-west-2`

Comment: I was THIS close to abandoning codeartifact. Thanks for reminding us about the region.